# How to confirm a specific user in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, put

So, I new in Angularjs and all this GET, PUT, Requests. However, I am creating an app where I have list of users in one page, and second page I have a form with three buttons. Which, I am focusing on one button which is the "Confirm" button. 
So, what I want to do with confirm button is want to confirm a specific user that will be called PUT /users/{userId}/confirm. I need help on this part. I have done the GET part of getting the users from backend. But, can't figure out with PUT request.

> Here is the code so far. 
>   **services**

```
 app.factory('people', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userInfo = {  
    getUserInfo: function () {
   return $http.get('https://admin/v1/unconfirmed_users');


     },




   };
   return userInfo;
  }]);

 app.factory('people', function($http){

 var services = {};
  services.getUserInfo = function() {

    return $http.put('https://users/{userId}/confirm');
  };
 return services;


})
```

> App.js

```
  var app = angular.module("Portal", ['ngRoute',  'ui.bootstrap' ]);


  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


     $scope.inactive = true;

     $scope.confirmedAction = function(person) {

     $scope.userInfo.users.splice(person.id, 1);


      location.href = '#/user';



        person.data = "true";
       console.log(person.data);
        console.log(person);





    };

  });


app.directive('confirmClick', ['$q', 'dialogModal', function($q, dialogModal) 
  {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // ngClick won't wait for our modal confirmation window to resolve,
            // so we will grab the other values in the ngClick attribute, which
            // will continue after the modal resolves.
            // modify the confirmClick() action so we don't perform it again
            // looks for either confirmClick() or confirmClick('are you sure?')
            var ngClick = attrs.ngClick.replace('confirmClick()', 'true')
                .replace('confirmClick(', 'confirmClick(true,');

            // setup a confirmation action on the scope
            scope.confirmClick = function(msg) {
                // if the msg was set to true, then return it (this is a workaround to make our dialog work)
                if (msg===true) {
                    return true;
                }
                // msg can be passed directly to confirmClick('Are you sure you want to confirm?')
                // in ng-click
                // or through the confirm-click attribute on the
                // <a confirm-click="Are you sure you want to confirm?"></a>
                msg = msg || attrs.confirmClick || 'Are you sure you want to confirm?';
                // open a dialog modal, and then continue ngClick actions if it's confirmed
                dialogModal(msg).result.then(function() {
                    scope.$eval(ngClick);
                });
                // return false to stop the current ng-click flow and wait for our modal answer
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}])

/*
 Modal confirmation dialog window with the UI Bootstrap Modal service.
 This is a basic modal that can display a message with yes or no buttons.
 It returns a promise that is resolved or rejected based on yes/no clicks.
 The following settings can be passed:

 message         the message to pass to the modal body
 title           (optional) title for modal window
 okButton        text for YES button. set false to not include button
 cancelButton    text for NO button. ste false to not include button

 */
.service('dialogModal', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return function (message, title, okButton, cancelButton) {
        // setup default values for buttons
        // if a button value is set to false, then that button won't be included
        cancelButton = cancelButton===false ? false : (cancelButton || 'No');
        okButton = okButton ===false ? false : (okButton || 'Yes');

        // setup the Controller to watch the click
        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, settings) {
            // add settings to scope
            angular.extend($scope, settings);
            // yes button clicked
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close(true);
            };
            // no button clicked
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };

        // open modal and return the instance (which will resolve the promise on ok/cancel clicks)
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: '<div class="dialog-modal"> \
              <div class="modal-header" ng-show="modalTitle"> \
                  <h3 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3> \
              </div> \
              <div class="modal-body">{{modalBody}}</div> \
              <div class="modal-footer"> \
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()" ng-show="okButton">{{okButton}}</button> \
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="cancelButton">{{cancelButton}}</button> \
              </div> \
          </div>',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                settings: function() {
                    return {
                        modalTitle: title,
                        modalBody: message,
                        okButton: okButton,
                        cancelButton: cancelButton
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        // return the modal instance
        return modalInstance;
    }
}])

 //Our routes
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/user", {
    controller: "HomeController",
    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
  })
  .when("/user/:id", {
    controller: "UserController",
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html"

})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/user'

  });

  });
```

Comment: ```return $http.put('https://admin/v1/users/' + userId + '/confirm',  {});```

Comment: should I put in my services? under $http.get?

Comment: I would add a new method, ```confirmUser: function(userId) { }```

Comment: can you please show me? also, should I put in my app.js where I have modules in there. I will show you in a bit.

Comment: I separate my services into own JS file, cleaner, not a giant app.js file

Comment: well, my services is in a separate js file

Comment: ```app.factory('people', function ($http) {
  var service = {};

  service.getUserInfo = function () {

  };
  service.confirmUser = function (userId) {

  };

  return service;
})```

Comment: can you check if I did it right?

Comment: ```services.confirmUser = function(userId) {
    return $http.put('https://users/' + userId + '/confirm', {});
  };``` is correct, you have defined two factories, only need one people factory with two methods

Comment: so, take out the second app.factory(people)?

Comment: correct, just add confirmUser method to existing factory

Comment: how can I check if it worked?

Comment: Ideally write tests ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.factory('people', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getUserInfo = function () {
        return $http.get('https://admin/v1/unconfirmed_users');
    };
    service.confirmUser = function (userId) {
        return $http.put('https://users/' + userId + '/confirm', {});
    };
    return service;
});
```